# Cloud function Parse.com with Tasker

Tags: parse-platform, tasker

Im trying to call cloud function from parse.com at Restask in Tasker
I already configured custom headers, parameter, etc.
But it always returns 400. And return body empty. Not sure why.

[image: Configuration of Headers]
[image: Return I'm getting]

Comment: would you mind sharing what you got so far?

Comment: Ill add screenshot as soon as i got in my pc

Comment: Tomaski, I added the screenshots from the configuration and result

Comment: Caio - unfortunately these screens do not provide any info on how you're trying to communicate with the server.
What url are you calling?
where and how do you store your session data?

Comment: Tomaski - I'm calling the url "https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello" and what session data should I store? I think I'll give up on this plugin and make one for myself byhand =D

Comment: for the most of REST API I know, you'd have to first log in with the server. You'd be given then a session tokenm which you'd have to send with every request.

anyway, if I read the manual correctly, to fetch a given cloud function, you need to use GET method and send X-Parse-Application-Id together with X-Parse-Master-Key have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah thats what im doing, sending them in headers

Comment: but on the screens you've provided, I see that you're using POST and sending X-parse-REST-API-Key, whereas API specification on their site states, that for api.parse.com/functions/functionName you must use GET and provide X-Parse-Master-Key. Have you tried it ?

Comment: Tomaski - I tried that out, but it doesnt returns anything, just keep on waiting...

Comment: Also tried to make my own, with Httpurlconnection in android, and got the same problem

Comment: I could use the SDK, but its a lot slower than the REST api...

Comment: I debugged with the get and it says "Method not allowed"

Comment: Ok, found the proble, it is not sending JSON in parameters, and it should be JSON

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar to what you're trying to do and just managed to POST an object into parse. The problem you're facing is that your request's body is empty (should be a JSON)
You can set that in RESTask's settings under "Custom body". 
I initially had problems with variables inside the body, but after talking to John from RESTask, he said that the variables work:

> it won't work, however, when you use the "test" function inside
>   RESTask, as there is no context of a task

Good luck and let us know what you've built .)

Z.